# Nginx doesn't work in local network

Tags: nginx, centos, localhost

os centos 6.3
Nginx doesn't work in local network, but it works in localhost. Tested by elinks.

```
# ps -ef | grep nginx
root      1447     1  0 Aug07 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
nginx     1448  1447  0 Aug07 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process

# netstat -napt | grep nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1447/nginx

# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

# cat /etc/sysconfig/selinux

# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this is not an Nginx problem. Do you see any access attempts in the Nginx access or error logs? You should if it's an Nginx issue.

Your `netstat` output shows that Nginx is running and listening on Port 80 on all IPs.

Try using `nmap` to port scan yourself and confirm something running on port 80 is detected:

```
nmap -vv -P0 (server IP address or DNS)
```

If it doesn't find anything, it sounds like it's being blocked somewhere else. Talk to your network administrator.